# How exactly should template classes be defined and implemented properly in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I recently decided to do some personal C++ practice by writing simple structures to ease into C++ development. My first attempt was to write a simple LinkedList but define it as a template class so that it could handle multiple data types. While doing so I did the standard practice of defining the class in a header file and implementing it in a cpp file and then I used make to build it (with `686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1`). As far as building the C++ files (which included a `Node.cpp`, `LinkedList.cpp` and `LinkedListIterator.cpp` everything worked fine with no complaints. I then introduce `main.cpp` which contained the main method and tried to create a `LinkedList<string>` (which worked) and then tried to call it's length function which I both defined and implemented:

```
// Other code here
LinkedList<string> *list = new LinkedList<string>();
cout << "Initial length: " << list->length() << endl;
delete list;
list = NULL; // I had defined NULL to be 0, pre 4.6 compiler so nullptr wasn't available
// End the main function
```

This threw an error that no `length()` function was defined for the templated `LinkedList<string>` class and so I began my research where I learned that template classes cannot be defined in the standard header/implementation format like standard C++ classes but none of these responses (mostly here) addressed how to properly handle template classes. So to finish off my personal exercise I dropped the headers and just defined and implemented the classes in the cpp file. Everything worked fine there.

There were some "work arounds" that supposedly made it possible to separate implementation from definition such as including the cpp file at the end of the header file (which failed to work for me) or, provided you only want your class to work with specific types, to declare static template versions of your class at the base of your header file like:

```
// Define a template class
template LinkedList<string>;
template LinkedList<int>;
// etc...
```

Which I didn't try (it may have worked, and as I was only doing a personal exercise it was perfectly acceptable) because this just feels wrong. Why make a template class if you lock it into certain types? I realize you could easily lock it into to all the major types you need giving you one definition for several data types but it just doesn't sit right with me to do things this way.

**TL;DR** Ultimately my question is, what is the proper way to define a template class and implement a template class in some kind of application/library other people would be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put everything - class definition *and* the class code - in the header. To see why, imagine a simple case:

```
// in .hpp
template <typename T>
T increment(T x);

// in .cpp
template <typename T>
T increment(T x) { return x + 1; }
```

Now you compile the .cpp only once. What code is it supposed to generate for the `increment` function? The `+` operator could be a floating point addition, or an integer addition, or a short integer, or even an overloaded `operator+`.

Then think about some other .cpp file where you're *using* the `increment` function:

```
// some other .cpp file
#include "increment.hpp"
...
  increment(a);
```

At *this* point, the compiler knows what type `a` is, so it could then generate the correct code for the `increment` function. But it doesn't know what the `increment` function looks like because it only sees the .hpp file and the code for `increment` is in the *.cpp* file.

Therefore, the only way to make it work is to put the declaration and the code in the .hpp file so that every time you *use* it, you have the definition and the compiler can generate the right version for the type you're using.

Comment: This is a good explanation, but I would say a bit more with respect to code organization.  One such practice that I have seen was to split the header into separate files--one ending with .h and the other with .hpp.  The .h file would declare the interface and would then `#include` the .hpp file at the end.  This provided clear separation between declaration and definition.  I think that `#include`ing a .cpp file from a header might be confusing because a .cpp file is generally considered to be a complete translation unit, but by having it contain a template definition, it actually isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Templates must be visible at the point of instantiation. Without explicit instantiation that basically means that the member function definitions must be available in the header for other translation units to instantiate it.

Comment: So instead of doing everything in a cpp file just do the definition and implementation in the header?

Comment: It helps to think of "member function definitions" as "member function definition **templates**". They aren't functions; they're patterns for making functions, so don't get compiled separately.

Comment: @PeteBecker Okay that makes a lot more sense.